# Reset style from copied line in phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to insert a new row, but currently it copies the style from the previous line by default. So, I need to reset the style of this new line. I am trying this code, but is not working:

Here is the error:

```
 Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::applyFromArray() in /var/www/xxxx/demo/xls.php
```

As the number of new lines is variable I can't specify a fixed range to select and add styles.

---

```
function styleResetBackground(){
    $styleBackground = array(
    'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF')
    )); 

    return $styleBackground;
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($lastRow+1,1)->applyFromArray(styleResetBackground());
```

---

The problem is the: `->applyFromArray(styleResetBackground()`, because without this code, the error disappear, but I need to reset the style after the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insertNewRowBefore()` method returns a Worksheet object. However, `applyFromArray()` isn't a Worksheet method but a Style method... you need to return a style method for the cells in the row you've just added, and then call `applyFromArray()` on that.... something like:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->insertNewRowBefore($lastRow+1,1)
    ->getStyle('A' . $lastRow . ':Z' . $lastRow)
    ->applyFromArray(styleResetBackground());
```